# Is there any way to delete a Confluence page and all of its children at once?

Tags: wiki, confluence

Is there any way to delete a [Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29) page and have it delete all of its children at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yu can do this through the API by basically scripting it yourself.

The [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) API supports:

1. deleting a page
2. getting all the children of a page

So between 1 and 2, you can keep recursively getting children and deleting these pages.

Be careful as this could be dangerous and wipe out lots of pages by accident if you have it start from the wrong page (although Confluence does have a recover feature.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with WebDav. Instructions for installing and setting up the WebDAV plugin can be [found here](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/WBDV/Confluence+WebDAV+Plugin).

- The confluence webdav endpoint is: `https://<server>/confluence/plugins/servlet/confluence/default/Global/`
- You can map it to a drive letter in explorer,
- Or access with eg Total Commander and davplug.wfx, or some other DAV client

Then just delete the directory corresponding to the page!

Comment: It took me just 30 seconds :) (With BitKinex WebDAV client previously configured :P)

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Delete Page Tree plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/at.rumpelcoder.confluence.deletepagetree/server/overview).

Answer (score -1):

Referring to [this thread](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-5974), this is not possible for the moment.

Comment: Not possible within Conf, but possible with other tools